# regex to match all .php file extensions in url except for if found in the admin section

Tags: php, regex, wordpress

I need to redirect all traffic on the live site to the same URL without the .php file extension, if the .php file extension is found.  However, since this is a wordpress site, I need to exclude wp-login.php and any .php extension found in a url that has wp-admin/* within it.

How can I accomplish this via a regex:

Currently, this matches all .php file extensions `(.*).php /$1`

But how to exclude wp-login.php and anytime the url contains wp-admin and ends with a .php extension?

Here's what I've tried for excluding wp-login.php, but isn't working, just not sure how to do this:
`(\/)(^[wp\-login])?(.*).php /$1`

How to do this properly?  And also exclude the wp-admin folder in the url with any strings that end with .php?

For example:

```
/testing.php - Needs to Match 
/wp-login.php - Should not Match 
/wp-admin/edit-post.php - Should not Match 
/wp-admin/tools.php?page=testing.php - Should not Match 
/product/category/testing.php - Should Match
```

Comment: Try `^/?(?!wp-login\.php$)(.*)\.php$ /$1`

Comment: revo, doesn't work https://regex101.com/r/f4GWDB/1/

Comment: @delboy1978uk You shouldn't paste it in regex101 as it is.

Comment: I didn't. I got rid of  `/$1`, obviously

Comment: @delboy1978uk You didn't escape the slash.

Comment: You mean YOU didn't escape the slash? :-P

Comment: @delboy1978uk In htaccess rules you don't have to because there is no delimiters involved. But somewhere like regex101 you should care.

Comment: Ah that's interesting, thanks for that revo, wasn't aware, although now i look it's glaringly obvious

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the regex you need:

```
^\/(?!wp-login|wp-admin).*\.php$
```

See the results here https://regex101.com/r/f4GWDB/2/

```
/testing.php   MATCH
/wp-login.php  X
/wp-admin/edit-post.php   X
/wp-admin/tools.php?page=testing.php   X
/product/category/testing.php   MATCH
```

Comment: Nice, But when I plugin this regex in, it is redirecting to `/(?!wp-loginwp-admin).*.php` instead of the url without the `.php` extension.  I believe I am not escaping something properly here.

Comment: Ah thats just the regex, now stick it in the htaccess rule, you'll need that  /$1 on the end

Comment: I am using nginx, so .htaccess is not the way I'm using this.  I am using the redirect wordpress plugin here:  https://wordpress.org/plugins/redirection/ in order to add the regex redirect.

Comment: Ooft. You are on your own from here on in then, good luck amigo!

Comment: Okie dokie, no problem.  You think I need to escapse certain characters here somehow?

Comment: You might need delimiters. Try wrapping my regex with some `#`'s on either side

Comment: I got it working like this:  `^\/(?!wp-login|wp-admin)(.*).php` and the `/$1` . Thank You So Much!

Comment: Ah great! Glad I could help! Can you mark this answer please? :-D

Comment: Done.  Have a great day.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following regex:

```
^\/((?!(wp-login|wp-admin)).*)\.php$
```

You can see the verification of the regex [here](https://regex101.com/r/Scpf6U/2)

```
/testing.php                           -  matches
/wp-login.php                          -  does not match
/wp-admin/edit-post.php                -  does not match
/wp-admin/tools.php?page=testing.php   -  does not match
/product/category/testing.php          -  matches
```

Comment: That's a strange match, you pick up a single letter g in each matches array

Comment: This doesn't work properly.  The match when true, replaces urls with an s at the end.

Comment: Could you provide a sample URL for this case? Because I thought all your URL's ended with `.php`.